# Jenkins wraps quotes around java system properties

Tags: java, testing, jenkins

I'm using Jenkins to execute a shell script at as a post build step. The problem is that jenkins wraps quotes around the system properties I'm passing in. Therefore the application can't see that any system properties have been passed in.

If Jenkins wrapped them in double quotes it would be fine but single quotes doesn't work.

Raw shell script:

```
java -jar -Dnetwork.configuration=Transport.uri=amqp://localhost:5672/stable,transportServer.database.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver,brokerServer.database.jpa=MYSQL "${WORKSPACE}/ffiq-integration/target/PackRunner.jar" -pack "${WORKSPACE}/ffiq-integration/src/main/resources" -name JenkinsIntegrationTests
```

Jenkins executes:

```
java -jar '-Dnetwork.configuration=Transport.uri=amqp://localhost:5672/stable,transportServer.database.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver,brokerServer.database.jpa=MYSQL' "${WORKSPACE}/ffiq-integration/target/PackRunner.jar" -pack "${WORKSPACE}/ffiq-integration/src/main/resources" -name JenkinsIntegrationTests
```

Is there a way to stop Jenkins doing this?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm having a similar issue passing passing the ${WORKSPACE} variable to a shell command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The single quotes shouldn't be a problem, the `java` process will still see the whole `-Dname=val` as a single option.  The more likely problem is that you need to swap round the order of the arguments, i.e. it should be

```
java -D.... -jar ".../PackRunner.jar" <arguments-to-PackRunner-main-class>
```

(with no other intervening arguments between the `-jar` and the JAR file name).